# Refresh variable in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this variable.php which contains a variable :

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

<body>

<div>

<?php


$output = shell_exec("sh r.sh");

$op = preg_split("#[\r\n]+#",trim($output));

$rest = substr("$op[0]",-5);

$value= hexdec($rest);

$value=$value/1000;

?>
<?php
$_SESSION["value1"] = "$value";
?>

</div>

</body>

</head>

</html>
```

and I have this index.php page which show me the variable value :

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

<body>
<?php print $_SESSION["value1"] ; ?>                        

</body>

</head>

</html>
```

How can I use Jquery to refresh the variable $value from variable.php and refresh it in index.php every 1 second ?

I tried this :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

setTimeout("location.reload(true)",1000);

</script>
```

But it only refresh the index.php but not the variable.php

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stackoverflow. We're here to help you with specific programming problems, not to write code for you. Show us what you've tried, share your thoughts with us and we'll help, but nobody is going to write code for you. First of all, no need for all those `html` tags in your variable.php, you're not displaying anything.

Comment: I tried this :<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

setTimeout("location.reload(true)",1000);

</script> but it refresh the index.php every 1 second but not the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `variable.php` do this:

```
<?php
    // Start the session
    session_start();

    $output = shell_exec("sh r.sh");
    $op = preg_split("#[\r\n]+#",trim($output));
    $rest = substr("$op[0]",-5);
    $value= hexdec($rest);
    $value=$value/1000;

    $_SESSION["value1"] = $value;
```

In your `index.php` do this:

```
<?php
    require_once('variable.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $_SESSION["value1"]; ?>
    <script>
        setTimeout(function(){
           window.location.reload(1);
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will run the code in `variable.php` everytime `index.php` is loaded. The JavaScript makes the page reload every single second.

This can also be done more elegant by making an AJAX call to a PHP page that updates the variable and returns the variable. If you want to use AJAX and jQuery read this article: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: It works great but the fact is I just want the variable to refresh. I will put some image in the php so every second it will refresh the image too and that's I don't want...

Comment: @Zekeriya Then you would have to look at the AJAX/jQuery part of my answer :-). Good reading.

Comment: I already read the article but I don't understand how it will be benefit for me ?

Comment: @Zekeriya Just make `variable.php` echo the `value` and make `index.php` load the data from `variable.php` every single second, with the jQuery.get(). The data in the jQuery.get() is the data (`variable`) you echo in `variable.php`. Replace the old `value` in ´index.php´ with the new data from the jQuery.get()-request with some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can work with ajax, here i put a example:

That is you index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
      $.ajax({ url: 'test.php',
             data: {action: 'test'},
             type: 'post',
             success: function(output) {
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = output;
              setInterval(myFunction(), 500);
                      }
          });


    }
    setInterval(myFunction(), 500);

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and for this example, you can use a php like this
test.php

```
 <?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>
```

you can change the result of test.php with other text, but if you put this line i think it will be more clear for you